# Handling a CSV with numerical values in Javascript and Google Visualization Table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The javascript code snippet below loads a csv file called numericalData.csv. The csv file contains a string of headers in the first row and a bunch of numbers from the second row. It then displays the data in [google visualization table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table)

How do I convert the numerical data into numerical values like float or integer. At present with the code below, it reads them as a string so the sort ascending and descending is all over the place (see screenshot below).

```
   google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {            
        var csvData = loadFile("numericalData.csv", ",");
            var csvParsedData = CSVToArray(csvData);

            data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(csvParsedData);


            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

            table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true});
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would expect to see if the array `csvParsedData` contains strings instead of numbers.  First, check your CSV to make sure your numbers aren't quoted.  If they are not, then the CSVtoArray function is not parsing numbers properly.  You can loop over your data calling `parseInt` or `parseFloat` as appropriate on each value in the `csvParsedData` array, and set the value in the array to the parsed value.  Here's one simplified example:

```
// parse all values in csvParsedData as int's
for (var i = 0; i < csvParsedData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < csvParsedData[i].length; j++) {
        csvParsedData[i][j] = parseInt(csvParsedData[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**[edit: updated code for handling different data types]**

Here's some code that will parse data types appropriately:

```
// columns is an array of data types corresponding to the data types of each column in the CSV array
var columns = ['string', 'int', 'float', 'int', 'int', 'float'];
// parse all values in csvParsedData as the appropriate data type
for (var i = 0; i < csvParsedData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < csvParsedData[i].length; j++) {
        switch columns[j] {
            case 'int':
                csvParsedData[i][j] = parseInt(csvParsedData[i][j]);
                break;
            case 'float':
                csvParsedData[i][j] = parseFloat(csvParsedData[i][j]);
                break;
            case 'string':
                break;
            default:
                // should never fire
        }
    }
}
```

You can add other data types as necessary.

Comment: Thanks +1. This could work but I'll have to work on separating the text string and the string of numbers to use your loop. Otherwise it'll convert these into Null or NaN. The headers for example are string of texts and column A is also text string.

Comment: Yes, of course.  As I stated in the answer, it was a simplified example.

Comment: See my update thanks. The floats are ok but strings needs sorting out.

Comment: I edited my answer with code that handles different data types as appropriate.  On a side note, the end result should be compatible with the `arrayToDataTable` method of building a DataTable, you don't have to resort to parsing rows into the DataTable individually, as in your response below.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an N rows x 5 columns array with asgallant fix implemented. Now I need to add a 6th column with only strings below it.

It would be something like

```
Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5 | String  |
1.234      3.5     4.2      2.1      2.2      Banana
```

With the current code below it's

```
 Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5 |
  1.234    3.5     4.2      2.1      2.2
```

Code

```
 var csvParsedData = CSVToArray(csvData);
// parse all values in csvParsedData as int's
for (var i = 0; i < csvParsedData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < csvParsedData[i].length; j++) {
        csvParsedData[i][j] = parseFloat(csvParsedData[i][j]);
    }
}

//data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(csvParsedData);
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number','Value1');
data.addColumn('number','Value2');
data.addColumn('number','Value3');
data.addColumn('number','Value4');
data.addColumn('number','Value5');
for (var j = 0; j < csvParsedData.length-1; j++){
    data.addRows([csvParsedData[j]]);
}
```